# Excel - How to add up values with a specific number criteria

Tags: excel, function, formula

Im currently trying to add up moneyvalue and taxvalue seperated from each other in 3 different categorys. 
(sum of tax1 [7%], sum of tax2 [19%] and the total value. So far no problem.

**Problem is** how to do so with the criteria that if I add a new row
(the red one in the picture) into the sheet it gets automaticly integrated into the formula and the total sum of tax depending on the the category it is (7% or 19%).  Here a picture of the sheet:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ANqW2l7.png]

I hope my question is understandable, thanks!

Comment: `=Sumif(C5:C10,19,D5:D10)` it should grow when lines are added.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you´ve really helped me out here! =)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely presumptuous but you seem to have plenty of room on your spreadsheet so I suggest considering an alternative data layout which would avoid the need to sum with criteria. So not really an answer to your question but perhaps a way to solve your problem. Separate out the two tax rates into separate columns and the values can then be summed according to column, rather than according to criteria which slightly complicate the equations:

[image: SO34077406 example]

The formula in D9 is just:

```
=SUM(D5:D8)
```

and this may be dragged across to E9 for the lower tax rate. F9 sums the two sums.

The D9 and E9 formulae include Row8 entries, which are populated with `'-` formatted Fill and don't contribute to the column totals but serve as a reminder that any inserted rows should be above the strings of hyphens.

@Scott's comment answers your question directly but would not suit if the row being inserted is immediately above `Sum of 19% tax`.